# I want to increment each time button is clicked!! VB.NET 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

It always shows the first condition. like if its clicked twice i want a1 and a2 to be visible and also label7 and label8 and soon... heres my code. Any help is appreciated

```
Private Sub cmdLap_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdLap.Click

Dim a As Integer

a = a + 1

If a = 1 Then

   a1.Visible = True

   Label7.Text = Label1.Text & " hour(s) " & Label2.Text & " minute(s) " &   Label3.Text & " second(s) "

ElseIf a = 2 Then

   a2.Visible = True

   Label8.Text = Label1.Text & " hour(s) " & Label2.Text & " minute(s) " & Label3.Text & " second(s) "

ElseIf a = 3 Then

    a3.Visible = True

    Label9.Text = Label1.Text & " hour(s) " & Label2.Text & " minute(s) " & Label3.Text & " second(s) "

End If
End Sub**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is local to the function so it's 0 each time you click, increments to 1, and you get that condition.

Move it to a class level property or field.

Comment: or declare it Static within the sub. Like this ->          Static a As Integer

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `a` is local to the Sub where is declared.
That means: every time this sub is invoked (user clicks the button) a new copy of `a` is created on the local stack and its values start again from zero.

You need to declare that variable outside the Sub.

```
Dim a As Integer

Private Sub cmdLap_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdLap.Click
  ......
End Sub
```

Of course now you have the opposite problem. The variable maintains its previous value and thus, after 4 clicks it reaches the value 4 and is no more matched by your tests.

By the way, do not use so undescriptive names for variables and controls. Try to use a more significative name to help your future coding efforts when six month from now, you will look back at this code.